# Flutter ios failing due to placeholder team ID

Tags: ios, flutter

Been following this introduction into provider for flutter https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8II1VPb-neQ

When getting to the final stage and running the app on the ios device I get the following error within the console:

Using new build systemnote: Planning buildnote: Constructing build descriptionwarning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the Runner editor. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

I've made sure flutter is updated, ios and android all running the latest versions.  This project ran perfectly fine before I made the changes outlined in the video...

Can anyone shed any light into what might be causing this issue?

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to your project and open iOS folder in Xcode
2. Go to the team section and select one
   [image]